# Tischler's Theorem on nonvanishing $1$-forms on open manifolds

Tags: reference-request, fibration, differential-forms

I have been trying to find a generalized version of the following theorem due to D. Tischler,

> **Theorem 1.** Let $M^n$ be a closed $n$-dimensional manifold. SUppose $M^n$ admits a nonvanishing closed $1$-form. Then $M^n$ is a fiber bundle over $S^1$.
>
> **Question.** More specifically, is there a version of this theorem for open manifolds either with boundary or noncompact?

Theorem 1 depends strongly on the fact that on a closed manifold $M$  we can find a finite basis for the de Rham cohomology group $H^1 (M, \mathbb R)$ such that given a basis $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_l$ of the free part of $H_1(M, \mathbb Z)$ we have
$$\int_{\gamma_j} \omega_j = \delta_{ij} \quad (Kronecker's \ \ delta)$$
for reference there is [Geometry, dynamics and topology of foliations a first Course, Rojas, Bruno, Scardua - Chapter 8].

So here we should be looking at a manifold with finite cover or $\mathcal l_2$-conditions, but I'm not sure where to  find material to work on this. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Either a paper or a book on the subject works just fine.

Here is the original paper by Tischler https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82577795.pdf.

Comment: I am not quite sure what conditions you could impose to make such a generalisation. For example $\mathbb{R}$ has a nowhere vanishing closed $1$-form $dx$.